# Pass text box value to a dojo grid's query parameter

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to pass the value in a text box as a query parameter in a dojo data grid and would like to get clarified on two questions listed below. The dojo grid initiates a call to the server with the query params to initiate a search and bring back results (that is diplayed on the data grid)

1. Is it possible to reload the gird based on the value in the text by invoking refresh (dijit.byId("mygrid").refresh
2. If yes, how can I pass the value of the text box as a query parameter to the data grid.

Listed below is my relevant code

```
        function reload(){
        dijit.byId("mygrid").refresh;
    }


     <div class="test"> 
            <input id="searchParam" >
            <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" onclick=reload()>
                Search
            </button> 


        </div>

    <div    dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
                                id="mygrid" 
                                jsid="mygrid"
                                      store="dojox.data.JsonRestStore"
     target="<c:url value='members' />">
                                query="{ 
                                searchCriteria: ? TODO How to pass value of text box here?,

                                }"
                                rowsPerPage="1000"
                                autoWidth="true"

                                autoHeight="true"
                                selectionMode="single"
                                selectable="true"
                                errorMessage="Error loading data"
                                noDataMessage="<span class='dojoxGridNoData'>No members found.</span>">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able do something like the following:

```
function reload() {
    var val = dojo.byId('searchParam').attr('value');
    dijit.byId("mygrid").setQuery({ propName: val });
}
```

You will need to properly build the query `{ propName: val }`.

Comment: Thanks @Craig Swing. I was able to invoke the reload() function and use .setQuery on the grid. I also ran into a filter() method on the grid, which did cause a similar call to the server but the grid did not refresh.

Comment: I was able to invoke the reload js() when I clicked on a button (onClick event).  Would you know how can I invoke the same upon user pressing ENTER key on a text box. I am not sure which event will trigger this. I tried using a dojo form (dijit.form.Form) and invoked the js at 'onSubmit' event. That seem to cause the entire page to reload and also did not pass the required parameters (thereby causing a different controller method to be invoked). Is there a way that I can avoid using the dijit.form.Form but still trigger the reload js when user clicks on ENTER key.

Comment: Never mind about my earlier query. Ran into this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/x3MMA/) from a different post. It did not do a full page reload, though it still uses a diji.Form. Have to understand it better. I think in my first example, I did not do the stopEvent().

Comment: any form, also dijit.form.Form will reload the page to the `action` href if its 'onsubmit' returns true. using dojo.stopEvent is mainly for `a` tags with onclick, override the `dijit.form.Form` `.onSubmit()` with a `if(this.validate()) dojo.xhrPost({url:this.action, form:this}); return false`